# Conservation of Energy and Birkhoff's theorem

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading the original paper by Bondi, van der Berg and Metzner ([link](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/269/1336/21)) regarding gravitational waves in asymptotically flat axisymmetric spacetimes. In the introduction, he makes the following comment -

> The conservation of mass effectively prohibits purely spherically symmetric waves and similarly, conservation of momentum prohibits waves of dipole symmetry.

I know that Birkhoff's theorem tells us that spherically symmetric asymptotically flat solution to GR is necessarily static, and therefore contains a timelike Killing vector, which implies conservation of mass (energy). Bondi et. al. seem to be stating the converse of this theorem, whose validity I do not immediately see. How do we show this?

Also, what is the corresponding proof of the second statement made above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set up a multipole expansion of the gravitational waveform.  You'll find that the monopole moment is proportional to the time derivative of the mass of the stress-energy tensor, and the dipole moment is proportional to the second time derivative of the momentum from the stress-energy tensor, both of which are conserved.  Thus, the first nonzero moment comes from the quadrupole moment.  This is worked out in great detail in MTW.